# how to prevent chain when adding javascript variables containing numbers

Tags: javascript, string, int

How can i prevent to javascript interpret my numeric vars from string vars?

```
var a = 100;
var b = -10
var c = a + b // 10-10 (string)
```

lets say i allways want

```
var c = a + b = 100+(-10) = 90 (number)
```

Comment: I don't normally do that, but, wtf?!

Comment: `c` will be a number, unless you do something like `c = a + '' + b;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example c will *always* be 90, however;

```
var a = 100;
var b = "-10";
var c = a + b // "100-10" (string)
```

to prevent this convert the string to an integer;

```
var c = a + parseInt(b, 10);
```

or with a unary+

```
var c = a + +b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code example...

```
var a = 100;
var b = -10
var c = a + b // 90 (number)
```

...won't do that unless one of the operands is a `String`. In your example, both are `Number`.

If you do have numbers inside of `String`s, you can use `parseInt()` (don't forget to pass the radix of `10` if working in decimal) or possibly just prefix the `String` with `+` to coerce it to `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/KCLEq/).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will always do the latter, as long as both of the variables you are adding are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The most concise way is prepending a `+` if you aren't certain whether the variables are numbers or strings:

```
var a = "100";
var b = "-10";
var c = +a + +b; // 90
```

This works since `+"123" === 123` etc.